# Tuple in MVC is getting null after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
 public ActionResult test(TestModel model)
    {
        var list = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
        foreach(var i in model.list)
        {
            list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(i.SomeString, i.SomeInt));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", new { TestList= list });
    }
 public ActionResult MyAction(List<Tuple<string, int>> TestList)
```

Why does "MyAction" gets only empty TestList?

Comment: Because you cannot pass a collection of complex objects to a GET method using `RedirectToAction` (look at the url your creating to understand). And you certainly can use a `Tuple` since it does not even have a parameterless contructor`.

Comment: If they are on the same controller create a local variable, but if they will redirect to another pages, you need to store it somewhere to be able to use its values session for example

Comment: Thank for help guys. Will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `TempData` dictionary in ASP.NET MVC to solve this problems.I think it would be perfect for you because it maintains data between redirects:

```
public ActionResult test(TestModel model)
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    foreach (var i in model.list)
    {
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(i.SomeString, i.SomeInt));
    }
    TempData["Tuple"] = list;
    return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController");
}

public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    List<Tuple<string, int>> list = TempData["Tuple"] as List<Tuple<string, int>>;

    if (list != null) { /*Do something*/}

    return View();
}
```

And it will work even if `MyAction` is in a different controller.Hope this helps you.